# Return rows with more than one comma separated value in a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called contacts and in that table there is a field called contact_type.

`contact_type` is varchar and stores comma separated values in a sting like this:

```
^Media^,^Historical^
```

However only a few rows out of thousands have more than one value stored and I need to to run a query that will return only the rows with more than one so if it stores just `^Historical^` then it will be ignored.

I’m pretty much stumped on how to build a query like this. I assume it will contain something like this:

```
SELECT LENGTH(@css) - LENGTH( REPLACE( @css, ',', '') ) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to select the records where `contact_type` contains a comma

```
select * from your_table
where instr(contact_type, ',') > 0
```